How can I get a DB2 instance/database for testing purpose
I'm trying to create a python program to connect to DB2 using pyodbc. It will try connect to DB2 using a connection string consisting of Driver, Database Name, Hostname, port, protocol, userID, password. But I do not have any database details to which I can connect and test my program.
How can I get access to DB2 ? Is there a way to use Db2 services online, if yes can I get it for free as I only need it for 2-3 days ?
Is there a way similar to how we download MySQL workbench and can create a database and tables.
I tried to use DB2 online but I could not get the correct direction where I could proceed. Also for downloading DB2 i did not get any clue.

If you have never used Db2-LUW before, then you have a substantial learning curve. If you are already experienced with Db2-LUW, the first option (docker container) below gives you greater flexibility, especially if you are competent with docker.
Stackoverflow is not a substitute for getting education or training.
Choose one of the options below , and take note that considerable study is required for any of the options:

Db2-community edition in a docker container running on your own computer  (easiest) , or Db2-Community edition  running on a suitably powerful local server that meets all the many pre-requisites for Db2-server ( you download the installable image, install it locally and configure it, after ensuring all prerequisites are in place). Start here https://www.ibm.com/blog/announcement/ibm-db2-developer-community-edition/

Db2-on-cloud, Lite plan (free with limitations), running on a remote cloud server controlled by IBM with many limitations on what you can do. Start here:
https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/Db2onCloud?topic=Db2onCloud-getting-started


After you have a running Db2-server (either located locally, standalone or in a docker container), you have to install pyodbc and IBM's clidriver on your own computer, (i.e. not on the Db2-server) and configure them to access your Db2-server.  This also requires  study if you've never done it previously, although the configuration is essentially trivial (but people often refuse to study the docs or fail to comprehend them).

To me the docker image is quite simple to use... if you already know the basics of docker, of course.
